# VB Macro for Excel - seems to work on cached values?

Tags: excel, caching, vba

I am very new to VB yet, so sorry if my question is not very clear.
I have coded a macro, which reads values from Sheet1 and writes some results to Sheet2 in Excel workbook. It also changes some values in Sheet1.
The macro can be executed multiple times and it will generate different results because some cells in Sheet1 will be changed after each execution.
And this works ok on my computer

However I sent the file to another person and when he executes the macro, he says that he gets the same result in Sheet2 each time (although the values on Sheet1 change after each execution).

Is it possible that the Macro uses a cached value of Sheet1 in the executions after the first? Is there something in the code, which I can call in order to avoid this?
Thanks

Comment: sharing your code (relevant section) will let us help you

Comment: Are you sure that the macro is running at the other user's computer? In new version of Excel you need to enable macros.